# NSMutableSet union set performance/implementation

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableset

I'm wondering how is union set implemented in an NSMutableSet instance. I have two large sets that needs to be unionized frequently and I'm wondering if I should implement my own way of unionizing two sets or if Apple's way is fast enough.

Comment: What makes you think you can do any better than Apple's implementation?

Comment: @KevinBallard That's still secondary to: "Does it even matter?" (As in, no performance profile; no performance concern.)

Comment: @KevinBallard I was planning on implementing a C version. Sets are going to have thousands of objects

Comment: @Zaph Apple's implementation makes Objective-C calls to `-isEqual` and `-hash` don't they?

Comment: @Ninja I doubt it, check the code. The underlying Core Foundation code is open source because it is used on the OS which is open source. At the bottom level is is just C function calls.

Comment: @Zaph If the objects in the set are obj-c objects, then it will end up calling `-hash` and `-isEqual:`. If they're CF objects then presumably it will use CoreFoundation equivalents.

Comment: Don't concern yourself too much with the overhead of message sending. There is a substantial amount of effort put into making it as efficient as possible and that includes providing shortcuts for commonly used messages such as `retain`, `release`, and I would assume `hash` and `isEqual:` also. ***Always*** profile first before refactoring. Code readability and maintainability should come first and foremost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of `NSMutableSet` depends greatly on the implementation of `-hash` and `-isEqual` by the objects in the set.  I would *not* think you'd get a performance boost implementing it yourself.  However, you could try it and then profile your code to see if it's "too slow."

Answer (score 1):

I would bet heavily that the Apple versions are heavily optimized. Why not just run Instruments and see if there is a performance issue?

For CFSet source code see: [opensource.apple.com](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFSet.c)

```
static Boolean __CFSetEqual(CFTypeRef cf1, CFTypeRef cf2) {
return __CFBasicHashEqual((CFBasicHashRef)cf1, (CFBasicHashRef)cf2);
}

static CFHashCode __CFSetHash(CFTypeRef cf) {
return __CFBasicHashHash((CFBasicHashRef)cf);
}
```

Comment: The backend isn't done yet but I'll write up some sample data to test it.

Comment: Sounds like a fun project.